# Adobe Flex 3: width and height specified in percentage not working for children of a viewstack

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, adobe, rendering

I have a `ViewStack` which is `dataProvider` for a `TabBar`. There are two `VBox`s as children for this `ViewStack`. It works fine with absolute values for width and height for these `VBox`s, but when specified in percentages, the `VBox` uses all the available space (100%) for any percentage value. Please find the code and screen shots below.

Can someone please explain why it is getting rendered so? And also how can children of a `ViewStack` be aligned to center? There is no `horizontalAlign` property for `ViewStack` and it is not working with `horizontalCenter= "0"`.

Code:

```
<mx:ViewStack id="viewStack" width="100%" height="100%" selectedIndex="0" horizontalCenter="0" textAlign="center">

    <mx:VBox label="Tab 1" width="25%" height="10%" borderThickness="2" borderColor="red"
        borderStyle="solid" horizontalAlign="left">

        <mx:Text text="This is tab 1" />

    </mx:VBox>

    <mx:VBox label="Tab 2" width="30%" height="20%" borderThickness="2" borderColor="haloBlue"
        borderStyle="solid">

        <mx:Text text="This is tab 2" />

    </mx:VBox>

</mx:ViewStack>
```

Image 1(with absolute values):
[image]

Image 2(with width="25%" and height="10%"):
[image]

Thanks,
Anji

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use an outer container that fills the space (which is what you want in a view stack) and put your content inside.  That outer container can center your inner content.  Like this:

```
<mx:Box label="Tab 1" width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="center">
    <mx:VBox  width="25%" height="10%" borderThickness="2" borderColor="red" 
              borderStyle="solid" >
        <mx:Text text="This is tab 1" />
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:Box>
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. Any explanation why it does not work without the outer container?

Comment: Yeah.  The ViewStack is likely wanting to take over the entire page because if it didn't, the experience would be odd.  It is literally a stack of views so you might see views below it.  Instead, you fill the stack with your box and then if you want other layout you can do it inside the larger panel.  Ultimately, it gives you more flexibility IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer the link

[View Stack Container](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=navigators_3.html) in that please read the

**Sizing the children of a ViewStack container**

by that U might get the clear Idea

If needed use another container inside the vbox

```
        ~~~ HappY Coding ~~~
```